# Limit bandwith of a wireless AP connected to Mikrotik routerboard (via another AP/router)

Tags: mikrotik, bandwidth-control

I have this topology:

```
       INTERNET
          |
  A  Mikrotik RB951G-2HnD
          |
  B  Wireless Router (can be set up as an AP/switch)
          |
  C  Guest Wireless AP
```

Is it possible to limit **C**'s bandwith without influencing **B**. **C** cannot be connected to **A** straight. Neither one of **B** nor **C** support bandwith limitation, so I could only try to set it on Mikrotik, if possible.

The reason I want the Mikrotik as a gateway is that it is the most powerful / reliable...

Thank you

Comment: What are the reasons for not being able to connect C - A? Is it possible to put a cheap VLAN capable switch (e.g. RB260GS) next to B and split B & C's traffic into separate vlans? (If it really is a 'guest' AP then that would be beneficial anyway)

Comment: @Matt the reason is that it is quite far away and goes through multiple walls. So it would be the very last option. Do you mean connecting the RB260GS to A instead of B?

Comment: I mean the following - Unplug everything in B and connect to a switch (D). Put new cable between switch D and B. You now just have A,B & C all connected directly to a switch (D) without any real cabling changes (Assuming you have power and space to put a small switch next to B). Even a cheap RB260 would now allow you to vlan trunk the traffic between A-D, allowing you to run the main wifi and guest wifi as completely independent subnets with their own IP range. You can then bandwidth limit the vlan interface or guest ip range at A

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Matt I like your suggestion, you can repost it as an answer, I guess I cannot accomplish this without a VLAN switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know the exact configuration (for instance I don't know whether **A** or **B** is handling DHCP), but I'm going to assume all 3 are effectively just on the same network and **A** manages everything.

As mentioned by pilsetnieks, if you could limit the guests to a specific IP range, it could be limited that way, although that may not be trivial or even possible depending on the exact hardware and setup.

My suggestion would be to do the following (Which is effectively the same as running a new cable from **A** - **C**, without having to run a cable).

1. Add a small vlan switch next to **B**. Seeing as you're already using Mikrotik, something like a RB260GS would be fine.
2. Plug **A** and **C** into the switch, and add a new cable between **B** and the switch

This just requires enough space next to **B** to place a small switch, a power outlet and a patch cable to connect it to **B**.

You can now configure the ports for **B** and **C** on the switch to be on independent vlans, and configure the port going to **A** to carry both. There'll also be some configuration on **A** to handle the vlans, but once configured this with effectively allow you to treat **A-B** and **A-C** as separate subnets with independent IP ranges. (I haven't done anything like this on Mikrotik for a while so I probably wouldn't be able to advise working config unfortunately. I think there's a few sample configs on the Mikrotik wiki)

This has the added benefit of splitting the guest traffic from everything else (which you really should do if it is actually guest traffic). You can use the firewall on **A** to allow or block traffic between the two networks if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can limit the guests (clients using C) to specific IP addresses or subnets, you can set up a simple queue in A targeting those addresses specifically. Open the Queue section, add a new simple queue, set the target IP address (or addresses, as a subnet,) and set the download and upload limits.

It would be even easier, if A was connected to C directly, then you could set the queue target to that interface, without worrying about IP addresses.

Comment: The problem is that the guest AP (C) is for real guests which I don't know the addresses of.